# How to merge attributes on a frequency table in R?

Tags: r, variables, merge, frequency-table

Assume that i have two variables. See Dummy data below:

**Out of 250 records:**

**SEX**

Male   :   100

Female :   150

**HAIR**

Short  :   110

Long   :   140

The code i currently use is provided below, For each variable a different table is created:

```
sexTable <- table(myDataSet$Sex)
hairTable <- table(myDataSet$Hair)

View(sexTable):
|------------------|------------------|
|       Level      |    Frequency     |
|------------------|------------------|
|        Male      |       100        |
|       Female     |       150        |
|------------------|------------------|


View(hairTable)
|------------------|------------------|
|       Level      |    Frequency     |
|------------------|------------------|
|        Short     |       110        |
|        Long      |       140        |
|------------------|------------------|
```

My question is how to merge the two tables in R that will have the following format As well as to calculate the percentage of frequency for each group of levels:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Variables      |       Level      |    Frequency     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Sex(N=250)     |        Male      |       100 (40%)  |
|                     |       Female     |       150 (60%)  |
|      Hair(N=250)    |        Short     |       110 (44%)  |
|                     |        Long      |       140 (56%)  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows` after converting to `data.frame`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(list(sex = as.data.frame(sexTable),
       Hair = as.data.frame(hairTable)), .id = 'Variables')
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
tbl1 <- table(mtcars$cyl)
tbl2 <- table(mtcars$vs)
bind_rows(list(sex = as.data.frame(tbl1), 
       Hair = as.data.frame(tbl2)), .id = 'Variables')%>% 
   mutate(Variables = replace(Variables, duplicated(Variables), ""))
```

If we also need the percentages

```
dat1 <- transform(as.data.frame(tbl1), 
  Freq = sprintf('%d (%0.2f%%)', Freq,   as.numeric(prop.table(tbl1) * 100)))
dat2 <- transform(as.data.frame(tbl2), 
  Freq = sprintf('%d (%0.2f%%)', Freq,   as.numeric(prop.table(tbl2) * 100)))
bind_rows(list(sex = dat1, Hair = dat2, .id = 'Variables')
```

Comment: that's a great suggestion. Thanks the values are returned as expected although after the results are printed the following error occurs:
`Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector`.
What it means?
Also the Variable should not be repeated when the levels have the same variables. (eg. Male and Female are both in Sex variable as shown in my question)

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou that is just a friendly warning.  It happens because one of the dataset have different column type (factor), so it is converted to `character` class.

Comment: sorry for asking again, what should I search for if I need to also provide the N (N of Sex = 250) near the Variable name. Question has been updated.

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou for this purpose, I would not replace the values to blank  you can do a filter easily if you keep the varriable as such `bind_rows(list(sex = as.data.frame(tbl1), 
        Hair = as.data.frame(tbl2)), .id = 'Variables')%>% 
        filter(Variables == 'sex', Freq == 11) %>% pull(Freq)#
[1] 11`